# Firestore: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

My firebase collection that I'm trying to query is literally empty. Zero documents inside. Even then, when querying it, I'm getting this error

I'm doing this inside a LAMBDA function on AWS. I know that the query works because it does return results sometimes but it's very random. Mostly it's just coming up with this error

Here are my lambda logs with following ENV variables turned on
GRPC_TRACE=all
GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG

[image: My Lambda Logs]

I have even tried this as I found this online somewhere but it didn't make any difference

```
db.settings({
  clientConfig: {
    interfaces: {
      'google.firestore.v1.Firestore': {
          methods: {
            RunQuery: {
              timeout_millis: 5 * 60 * 1000
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Here's what my query code looks like

```
let snap = await db.collection('notifications').where("siteID", "==", msg.siteId).where("procCode", "==", code).where("aptNum", "==", msg.affectedRows[0].after.AptNum).get();
```

Here's the output I get eventually. Not even in the same lambda execution but in a separate one which is also strange.

[image]

Comment: I suggest doing a search for this error message, because it comes up a lot, and there are some very well known limitations of Firestore that you might be running into.

Comment: I've done that and I'm posting this after doing extensive research and trying many things found on the web as suggested in the post.

Answer (score 20):

I figured out what my issue was here. I was calling the Firebase API inside an async function but the caller of that function wasn't "await"ing that call which led to this. It all works now.

Comment: Thank you. I doublechecked my code and also have just found the same my own mistake.

Comment: I just stumbled upon a similar issue. How did you block/ await the insertion caller function then? In my case, the caller, which is firestore insert() is not being blocked.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question exactly but as I mentioned in my last comment, I simply just had to add "await" in front of my function call.

Comment: I have similar issue while deleting a document, but I do have `await` in my delete function call. Any thoughts?